# SSH key-based auth asks for password on first login

Tags: 16.04, login, password, openssh, two-factor-authentication

I have a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS system and have noticed that key-based SSH authentication asks for the account's password the first time I login to the machine and subsequent SSH attempts work without prompting for a password.

So far, the behavior can be reproduced by rebooting the machine.  There may be a timeout as well, but I'm in the process of setting up the machine and haven't encountered it yet.

In general this is pretty neat as it mitigates a compromised SSH key, though it has a drawback for automated processes; in my case config management with Ansible.

Where is the SSH server behavior configured?  Specifically, to ask for password authentication even if a key-based auth succeeds, but only the first time the key is used to open a session.

I'd like to keep this "two-factor"ish behavior for interactive sessions, but disable it (i.e. do not prompt for password) for certain accounts (e.g. a dedicated `ansible` user).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an idea why the password is only requested once? I don't know of any mechanism that caches remote account passwords for SSH. Are you sure the password challenge stems from the SSH server and not from a local key chain manager or something like that?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for:  https://sysconfig.org.uk/two-factor-authentication-with-ssh.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Terrance.  This is a good lead for setting up 2FA the right way.  After some digging, I found the answer to my question here.  See below in a bit for my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer on another stack exchange.  The reason for this behavior is that the home directory is encrypted!

[Why am I still getting a password prompt with ssh with public key authentication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48910/122815)

> Is your home dir encrypted? If so, for your first ssh session you will have to provide a password. The second ssh session to the same server is working with auth key. If this is the case, you could move your authorized_keys to an unencrypted dir and change the path in `~/.ssh/config`.

I tracked this by looking through `/var/log/auth.log`, and specifically, the line:

```
pam_ecryptfs: Passphrase file wrapped
```

Searching for that led me to the other stack exchange answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the password from the private key the SSH agent will not ask for one. Assuming that the machine-only account is called `ansible` like in the question you can achieve it with this command:

```
sudo -u ansible ssh-keygen -f ~ansible/.ssh/id_<TYPE> -N ''
```

or

```
sudo ssh-keygen -f ~ansible/.ssh/id_<TYPE> -N ''
```

depending on your access rights management configuration (replace `<TYPE>` with the key type in question, e. g. `rsa`, `ecdsa`, `ed25519` etc.).

---

Password-less machine keys are common practice and safe enough as long as one

- uses a unique dedicated key for the service using the key (not the same as the key used by the service developer(s)!) and
- replaces the key and removes it from all `authorized_keys` files at the first sign of a potential compromise (which is facilitated by the measure described at the previous bullet point).

Of course the key file should have the access mode `0500` to restrict access to the machine account only. That's the default access mode for keys created with `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: Thanks, though the _key password_ is not the one I'm being prompted for.  It's the _account password_ on the remote machine.